# Throw some light on how to disable confirmation only if user signs up through a provider using devise ruby on rails.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I tried to define a function no_provider

devise :databse_authenticatable, :registerable (#blah blahs)

```
if no_provider?
  devise :confirmable
end
```

No success so far.

I have a bad feeling about this though. Throw me some light on my approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[When in doubt, check the documentation.](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Confirmable)

[The source code also has the answer.](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/2aedb1bf795947f189183fbd1e479719463f6395/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb#L162-L164)

There's a callback method you can override to achieve exactly what you want:

```
# app/models/user.rb
def confirmation_required?
  no_provider? && super
end
```

So use this method and just include the `devise :confirmable` line as usual.

Comment: Will check up the documentation and source code before I post any questions from now on. There is another method defined called 'skip_confirmation!'. Pretty much did my job. Thank you.